# cannot return a utc datetime with moment.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, momentjs

trying to pass a datetime object that has already been converted to UTC by momentjs to my MVC controller.  I'm using a kendo datetimepicker, and for some reason, moment.utc just will not send the controller the value that i want.  For example, i type in '9/17/2015 12:00 AM' into my kendo datetimepicker. I get this value like:

```
var start = $("#startTime").val();
```

which gives me "9/17/2015 12:00 AM" .  great.  then i convert this to a date object:

```
var t1 = new Date(start);
```

which reads as Thu Sep 17 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) {} .  Still looking good.  Next i try to convert to UTC with moment using:

```
var t2 = moment.utc(t1);
```

this gives me

```
dt {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Thu Sep 17 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), _isUTC: true, _locale: fu, _d: Thu Sep 17 2015 00:00:0...
```

did NOT convert to utc.  instead of converting all it seemed to do was take a date object and let me tell it 'hey, this is utc' and it said 'ok' (by flagging _isUTC:true), even though it's still saving the GMT value in there

even if i decided to make a moment object first, and then run UTC on it?  it still comes out the same:

```
var t2 = moment(t1);
var t3 = moment.utc(t2);
```

So either of those values, if i run .format() on them (which is what i need to pass to my controller), i always get "2015-09-17T07:00:00+00:00", which is NOT the UTC time.  It's the exact time i typed in.  What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Don't even look at the fields prefixed with underscores.  They're part of the internal design of moment.js, and not meant for direct consumption.  In many cases, several of the fields have to be combined to get the correct results.  This is accounted for in the functions of the public API, such as `format`.
- Don't rely on the `Date` object to do your parsing.  Results can be inconsistent across browsers.  Moment has its own parser, which you can use like this:

  ```
  moment("9/17/2015 12:00 AM","M/D/YYYY h:mm A")
  ```

  However, in your particular case, you actually don't need to parse any string at all.  You said you're using Kendo's `DateTimePicker` control, so you should use the [`value`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datetimepicker#configuration-value) function, which already returns a `Date` object.
- Moment has two different functions for working with UTC.

  - `moment.utc(value)` - interprets values in terms of UTC
  - `m.utc()` - where `m` is any moment instance, *converts* the value to UTC

  Note that the second one it *mutates* the existing instance by switching it from "local mode" to "UTC mode".  It also returns the instance if you want to chain functions, but it does modify the original instance as well.
- You can use `format` after converting to UTC if you want the output to show the `+00:00` offset.  However, if you want to show `Z` (which is usually preferred), you you can just call `.toISOString()` without explicitly going to UTC first - since that function *always* outputs UTC.

  Additionally, most modern browsers *already* support `.toISOString()` directly on the `Date` object, so unless you're targeting older browsers, you might not need moment at all.
- You said `"2015-09-17T07:00:00+00:00"` was not the UTC time, but actually *it is*.  You started with 00:00 in UTC-7, which is equivalent to 7:00 in UTC+0.  So despite jumping through several unnecessary steps, moment still got it right in the end - at least with `t3`.

You can simplify your code with any of these:

```
var picker = $("#startTime").data().kendoDateTimePicker;
var dt = picker.value();  // dt is a Date object
var m = moment(dt);       // m is a moment object
m.utc();                  // m has been converted to UTC
var s = m.format();       // ex: "2015-09-17T07:00:00+00:00"
```

Or...

```
var picker = $("#startTime").data().kendoDateTimePicker;
var dt = picker.value();  // dt is a Date object
var m = moment(dt);       // m is a moment object
var s = m.toISOString();  // ex: "2015-09-17T07:00:00Z"
```

Or...

```
var picker = $("#startTime").data().kendoDateTimePicker;
var dt = picker.value();  // dt is a Date object
var s = dt.toISOString(); // ex: "2015-09-17T07:00:00Z"  (requires browser support)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.  Oddly enough it still wasn't working right for me, and i made sure that the javascript was working right (http://plnkr.co/edit/JchbfJqAwJwIr8zm803K?p=preview ), but apparently one of the other problems i was having was that my MVC controller was taking a datetime parameter as the input.  This, for some reason, converted the object BACK to local time.  Once i changed that parameter to a string instead, it worked right.  Weird.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that can be an issue with ASP.NET MVC.  Though if you used WebAPI instead, you wouldn't have that issue because deserialization is handled by JSON.net.  You might also try `DateTimeOffset`.